# In Bootstrap, how do I increase the spacing between list items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My full code:

It's a footer implemented with an unordered list, for example:

```
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a class="text-muted" href="" target="_blank">Contact Us </a>
      </li>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Predefined bootstrap classes for [Typography](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities)

Suppose for margin top you can use class="mt-1"
similarly for

**margin bottom (mb-1) , left (ml-1) and right (mr-1) ranges from 1-9**

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the li:

```
 li{
    padding-right:1rem;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin right to items

```
.list-inline-item{
  margin-right:10px;
}
```